# How do I tell what ports are being listenend on by processes inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, node.js

Docker newbie here.

I am running a node.js utility inside a docker container. This utility is supposed to start a web server, but I don't know if its working.

What can I use to see which ports are open for listening inside a container, so I can expose the appropriate port to my host machine?  Normally I would use netstat to check what ports are being listenend on by processes but docker doesn't have netstat.

Comment: Which host os? On linux you can explicitly `nsenter` a container to run commands without changing filesystem root.

Comment: The host is Windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this web page: https://linux-audit.com/audit-which-ports-are-used-by-a-linux-process/

It mentions the ss command, which is present in my ubuntu based docker container.

So I was able to find the port by running:

```
ss -lpntu
```